# VBA dynamic formula stumped

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a small piece of code within a larger macro that is stumping me.

When I run it I get the Runtime 1004 error application defined or object defined error.

Can someone point out where my code is incorrect?  I assume I've made an error in the 8th line, where I define the range.

LastCol is calculating correctly (the result is currently a value of 4).

The intent is for the macro to populate the current tab, row 37 & 38 column i with the data from every worksheet in the work book in row 41 and 42 column LastCol.

Thanks!

```
Sub col_count()


n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Dim LastCol As Integer
    With Sheets(2)
        LastCol = .Cells(41, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With


For i = 2 To n
Range(Cells(37, i), Cells(38, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(41, LastCol), Cells(42, LastCol)).Value
Next i

Rows("37:38").NumberFormat = "#0.00%"




End Sub
```

Comment: ***ALL*** Range objects need to be assigned a parent sheet.  This includes `Cells`: `Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Cells(41, LastCol), Sheets(i).Cells(42, LastCol))`  You should also, put the parent sheet to the other `Range()`,`Cells` and `Row`

Comment: As always, thanks @ScottCraner